# How to add ngDisabled after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I am working with angularjs and Kendo controls. I am creating two Kendo DatePickers after the DOM is loaded.

I need to disable them under one condition, when I place `ng-disabled` in my .cshtml file, I am not able to create Kendo DatePicker.

I was wonder is there a way to add `ng-disabled` to DatePicker control after it is rendered?

**Setting up kendo DatePicker:**

```
$("#txt-add-plan-effective-from, #txt-add-plan-effective-till").kendoDatePicker({
    min: new Date("01", "01", "1900"),
    format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
    parseFormats: "MM/dd/yyyy"
});
```

**ng-disabled condition:**

```
hiosNumber == undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried ng-disabled="!hiosnumber" . Because every model value is set to undefined untill it is not set from the scope or from the ng-init.

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar I want to disable the control only when it's undefined, the model is bind with a select control and the user changes it's value, when it's not undefined I am enabling the datepicker control

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar I tried out your suggestion but still the control is not getting created, when the text box is loaded in disabled state!